# Time difference between CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_DATE() + 0 and CURRENT_DATE()

Tags: mysql

When I perform this query:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),CURRENT_DATE()+0,CURRENT_DATE;
```

I get this result:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_DATE()+0, CURRENT_DATE
2019-03-25 08:54:33, 20190325        , 2019-03-24
```

Why is the difference between CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE + 0?

My server version is: 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Thank you for any suggestion :)

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f85d41c9c1dd6942207c4458df4dd8fc

Comment: @Nick I think the `2019-03-24` is a copying typo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, it is a locale difference. Works for me.

Comment: How can a locale difference explain a different calendar day between the current timestamp and current date? (Hi EJP, by the way, if that's you)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Because of timezones for a start. [EJP]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some number of days to a MySQL date, then you should use `INTERVAL`, e.g.

```
CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 0 DAY
```

But, since you actually an integer to a MySQL date, here is an explanation.  `CURRENT_DATE()` is a date, while `CURRENT_DATE() + 0` ends being a number.  Your current query:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() + 0;
```

is actually being evaluated as this:

```
SELECT (CAST CURRENT_DATE() AS UNSIGNED) + 0;
```

The cast to integer is necessary because you are adding zero, an integer, to the result of `CURRENT_DATE()`.

Convince yourself of this by running:

```
SELECT (CAST CURRENT_DATE() AS UNSIGNED);
```

This will return `20180325` as a result.

Comment: Is it worth making a point about `CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 0 DAY` being the appropriate way to do date math?

Comment: Hi, I understand that - my question is why there is date difference when I do CURRENT_DAY I get 24th March and when I do CURRENT_DAY+0 I get 25th March. :)

Comment: @JakubKužílek Are you sure this is reproducible?  I cannot reproduce your behavior, [see this demo](https://rextester.com/LMDKT52516).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not sure, and I have no idea why this is happening, thus I am asking :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the result can be somewhat surprising. You add zero to a date and expect it to stay this date. This, however, would imply that you add zero "something", e.g. zero *hours* or zero *days* (otherwise: would would +1 mean to a date?).

There are DBMS that do exactly this. In Oracle for example `somedate + 1` means `somedate + interval '1' day`. MySQL, however, doesn't. MySQL rather adds the number (zero in your case) to the internal numeric representation of the date. Why they are doing this, is beyond me. Why would we want to see what MySQL uses internally to store a date? It shouldn't matter to us. So what MySQL does is convert `CURRENT_DATE` to a numeric value and then add zero, which is why you see a number in your result.

What you can learn from this: Don't add a number to a date, as it has no meaning really. What is October 3, 2008 plus 23 (opposed to "plus 23 days" or "plus 23 weeks"  or whatever)? It just has no meaning. So treat this like a flaw in the DBMS to even allow this and just never use it.

You can of course always add an interval to a date, e.g.

```
select current_date + interval 0 day;
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: My point is another. I posted this to show that one should just not add a number to a date, as this makes no sense. The OP should ask themselves what they wanted to express with adding a number to the date and write a proper expression with an interval instead. MySQL should not reveal storage internals, a date should not be implicitly convertible to some number in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting. And can you explain why CURRENT_TIMESTAMP date 25th March differs from CURRENT_DAY date 24th March?

Comment: Oops, I thought this was a typo. Sorry. If `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `CURRENT_DAY` return different dates, I consider this a bug. MySQL docs say: "The CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIME(), CURRENT_DATE(), and FROM_UNIXTIME() functions return values in the current session time zone" (here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html). You are not using MySQL, but MariaDB, but this shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I am slightly confused, why two functions return two different date values with similar timezone... Or I have no idea, if it is possible to have two different timezones in one sql query :)

Comment: As I said: I consider this a **bug** if the two functions return different dates in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer - the problem lies in dataGrip desktop client I am using. I am not sure what exactly happens to data, but it seems, that a) dataGrip somehow makes the connection with incorrect timezone or b) incorrectly converts data when receiving. And before you asked, I tried the same query via terminal, MySQL workbench and on the MySQL server itself and I get the correct answer. :)